# pst-poker face cards fail with lualatex

Tags: graphics, luatex, pstricks, epstopdf, luapstricks

Commands for face cards in the [pst-poker](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/pst-poker) package produce an error when compiling with lualatex. The following example works with latex+dvips and xelatex but not with lualatex:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pst-poker}

\begin{document}
\crdQc
% \crdAs non-face cards work fine
\end{document}
```

The error is `` ! Package luatex.def Error: File `Queen-club-color-eps-converted-to.pdf' not found: using draft setting. ``. The error shows up with both miktex and texlive. It looks like an issue with the eps to pdf conversion.

Is this issue coming from [luapstricks](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/luapstricks) or the package?

Comment: This was fixed in version 0.3b (CTAN announcement [here](https://www.ctan.org/ctan-ann/id/mailman.3921.1676388707.3715.ctan-ann@ctan.org))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

looks like an issue with the graphics package doing the conversion in the background, but you can (more efficiently) pre-convert

[image]

Just run

```
epstopdf /usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pst-poker/Queen-club-color.eps Queen-club-color-eps-converted-to.pdf
```

Before lualatex (adjusting the input path to your system)

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Though am I wrong in thinking this should “just work” without the pre-conversion?

Comment: @mbert er well that depends. It  would be nice if it did but maintaining all the components to find input flles that are somewhere in tex's search path (but not in their path) is tricky especially while keeping to what is allowed in restricted shell escape, so no intermediate files or redirects. simpler would be if the package included pdf versions and used them directly witth pdf back ends.